# Access 2007: How to do weekstart and weekending and have the weekending dates show on result

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Ok, I have a query that needs ALL of the weekending DATES to show on the output as well as doing the counts of `callID`s reviewed within the week that starts Sunday and ends on Saturday?

Currently I am plugging in the startdate and enddate but this does not accumulate the weekendings in the output.

Meaning what I want to see in the output is:

- Weekending 2/7/2015 count of 15 (for each supervisor)
- Weekending 2/14/2015 count of 25
- Weekending 2/21/2015 count of 9

  SELECT DISTINCT [Coach].[LastName] & ", " & [Coach].[FirstName] AS CoachName, Count(S.CallId) AS [Count], tblLocations.LocationName, S.DateScored
  FROM tblLocations INNER JOIN (tblScores AS S INNER JOIN tblEmployees AS Coach ON S.CoachId = Coach.ID) ON tblLocations.ID = S.LocationId
  GROUP BY [Coach].[LastName] & ", " & [Coach].[FirstName], tblLocations.LocationName, Coach.Source, S.Completed, S.DateScored
  HAVING (((tblLocations.LocationName)="Nashville" Or (tblLocations.LocationName)="Solon" Or (tblLocations.LocationName)="San Antonio" Or (tblLocations.LocationName)="Phoenix") AND ((Coach.Source)="Supervisor") AND ((S.Completed)=Yes) AND ((S.DateScored)>=[Start Date] And (S.DateScored)<=[End Date]));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a few Access SQL functions: `IIF()`, `Weekday()`, and `DateAdd()`. Essentially, you have to find a date's [weekday number](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/weekday.php) (1-7, corresponding to Sun-Sat) and then add a corresponding value to get all dates to return Saturday dates:

```
SELECT [Coach].[LastName] & ", " & [Coach].[FirstName] AS CoachName, 
     Count(S.CallId) AS [CountOfSupervisors], tblLocations.LocationName,  
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 7, S.DateScored,
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 6, DateAdd('d', 1, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 5, DateAdd('d', 2, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 4, DateAdd('d', 3, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 3, DateAdd('d', 4, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 2, DateAdd('d', 5, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 1, DateAdd('d', 6, S.DateScored), Null))))))) As EndOfWeek

FROM tblLocations INNER JOIN (tblScores AS S 
INNER JOIN tblEmployees AS Coach ON S.CoachId = Coach.ID) ON tblLocations.ID = S.LocationId 
WHERE (((tblLocations.LocationName IN ('Nashville','Solon','San Antonio','Phoenix') AND 
        ((Coach.Source)='Supervisor') AND ((S.Completed)=Yes) AND 
        ((S.DateScored)>=[Start Date] And (S.DateScored)<=[End Date]))

GROUP BY [Coach].[LastName] & ", " & [Coach].[FirstName], tblLocations.LocationName, 
     Coach.Source, S.Completed, 
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 7, S.DateScored,
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 6, DateAdd('d', 1, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 5, DateAdd('d', 2, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 4, DateAdd('d', 3, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 3, DateAdd('d', 4, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 2, DateAdd('d', 5, S.DateScored),
     IIF(Weekday(S.DateScored) = 1, DateAdd('d', 6, S.DateScored), Null)))))));
```

Alternatively, here is a less verbose solution as identified by @HansUp without nested `IIF()` statements:

```
SELECT [Coach].[LastName] & ", " & [Coach].[FirstName] AS CoachName, 
    Count(S.CallId) AS [CountOfSupervisors], tblLocations.LocationName,  
    DateAdd('d', IIf(S.DateScored Is Null, 0, 7 - Weekday(S.DateScored)), S.DateScored) As EndOfWeek

FROM tblLocations INNER JOIN (tblScores AS S 
INNER JOIN tblEmployees AS Coach ON S.CoachId = Coach.ID) ON tblLocations.ID = S.LocationId 
    WHERE (((tblLocations.LocationName IN ('Nashville','Solon','San Antonio','Phoenix') AND 
    ((Coach.Source)='Supervisor') AND ((S.Completed)=Yes) AND 
    ((S.DateScored)>=[Start Date] And (S.DateScored)<=[End Date]))

GROUP BY [Coach].[LastName] & ", " & [Coach].[FirstName], tblLocations.LocationName, 
    Coach.Source, S.Completed, 
    DateAdd('d', IIf(S.DateScored Is Null, 0, 7 - Weekday(S.DateScored)), S.DateScored);
```

You will notice I adjusted some of your code. You can move all your `HAVING` statements into a `WHERE` clause (`HAVING` is used when aggregates are expressed - Count, Sum, Avg, First, Last). Also, you can use the `IN()` clause for multiple OR conditions. Hope this works!

Comment: Consider `DateAdd('d', IIf(S.DateScored Is Null, 0, 7 - Weekday(S.DateScored)), S.DateScored) AS EndOfWeek` instead of those nested `IIf` expressions. Also `SELECT DISTINCT` is not useful in a `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: Thank you all and I will get into these responses as soon as I am done with reports I gotta produce :S